# How to use XPath with MSHTML?

Tags: delphi, mshtml

How to use/mimic XPATH using MSHTML in Delphi? This is how its done with HTML Agility Pack

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]")
```

Is something like this possible with Delphi?

Comment: I would rather query [`IHTMLDocument2::images`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752593(v=vs.85).aspx) and iterate the returned collection. But it's just my personal preference.

Comment: Take a look at this post on the Rodrigo's blog: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/category/xpath/

Comment: @TLama I have found [this](http://pastebin.com/vbu4ANSh) .. however it is for C#.

Comment: Well, that code somehow mimics basic XPath expressions by using RegEx. Yes, it might be translated to Delphi, I think. But the question is why :-) XPath is not for HTML and if I would need to get a collection of certain elements, I would use the way I mentioned. Hence my comment.

Comment: @TLama Less code.. :) I will try to translate and post as an answer, unless someone beats me to it.. :)